# Aggregate data to show text in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I need to put together multiple entries into one where the result is text and has to be in one cell.

**From this data in `A:B`**
*This is a sample; the actual list in Column A may be extremely long.*

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Adam | apple |
| **2** | Adam | coke |
| **3** | John | cake |
| **4** | Kim | orange |
| **5** | Kim | water |
| **6** | John | apple |
| **7** | Adam | water |

[image: table 1]

**To this in `C:D`**

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Adam | apple | **Adam** | **apple, coke, water** |
| **2** | Adam | coke | **John** | **cake, apple** |
| **3** | John | cake | **Kim** | **orange, water** |
| **4** | Kim | orange |  |  |
| **5** | Kim | water |  |  |
| **6** | John | apple |  |  |
| **7** | Adam | water |  |  |

[image: table 2]

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent precedent on StackOverflow for this question - though I can't locate it just as the moment. This solution is based on [How to do a "group concat" in an ARRAYFORMULA?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/8838747?hl=en) in the Google support form.

Let's assume that your raw data is in Columns A and B, and the output will be in Columns C and D.

Insert this formula in Cell C1.
`=Arrayformula(unique({A1:A, substitute(Trim(transpose(query(if(transpose(A1:A)=A1:A,B1:B&Char(10),),,9^99))),char(10),",")}))`

---

**BEFORE - raw data**

[image: Before]

---

**AFTER - additional data**

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

```
=MAP(TOCOL(UNIQUE(A:A),1), LAMBDA(r,
     {r, JOIN(", ", FILTER(B:B, A:A=r))}))
```

[image: above formula in C1 showing expected results]

## Explanation

1. A column of unique names is created from column A:

   1. First, UNIQUE is applied to column A, `A:A`, which returns an array of unique names and one empty value representing all the empty rows in column A.
   2. TOCOL is then used to remove the empty value by setting its **ignore** argument to `1`
2. For each unique name `r`, the LAMDA's formula returns a 2-column, 1-row array where:

   1. Column 1 is the name stored in `r`
   2. Column 2 is a set of delimited column B values where column A matched `r`:

      1. FILTER is used to get the column B values that meet the condition
      2. JOIN is used to concatenate those values delimited by a comma followed by a space `,` .
3. The LAMBDA formula repeats once for every unique column A name that's mapped in.

## Sheets Functions

[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)  [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)  [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)  [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en)  [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en)  [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en)  [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en)